# Markdown failure in code sample?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I can't figure out why one line of the code sample in this answer shows as normal text, does anybody have a clue?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534328/5987

Comment: I suspect you had some `&nbsp;` or so in the leading whitespace on that line. I deleted it and readded spaces, now it's fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I used copy/paste to copy the line from the previous version of the answer; perhaps I copied from the preview instead of the text box? It's never happened to me before in all these years though. P.S. I saw your fix, worked great. Did you just replace the spaces?

Comment: There's always a first time. Copy-pasting from somewhere is one of the more common ways to introduce breaking whitespace, could be that indeed. Yes, only spaces, nothing else.